# Salesforce Record Types Issue

Tags: salesforce

I have came across very interesting problem which I think it's on Salesforce's end but I would like to hear your thoughts on this.

If any of you used Formula Fields to bring a record type name from a particular record to another record might have seen this.

For an example I have record type called "Record Type X" on opportunity and "Record Type Y" on the account record.

When I use `$RecordType.Name` in the formula fields (RTNameAcc_*c & RTNameOpp*_c) on both records, the name of their record type is coming across correctly. However, the problem occurs when I reference the account record type on the opportunity record. If I create new formula field on the opportunity called `AccountRTName__c` and put the following formula `Account.RTNameAcc__c` instead of the related Account record type name (Record Type Y), I'm getting the opportunity record type name (Record Type X) instead.

I am aware that the formula in `AccountRTName__c` becomes `Account.$RecordType.Name` which is fine and should get the Account record type.

So my question is: Is it correct that when you use `$RecordType` in any context and formula field, the record type is referencing to parent object of the field? And if so, does anyone have a different solution to this problem (without using custom settings)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, the $ context variables are resolved in a non-intuitive way in this use case. It's been a long time since I've dealt with this issue, but the solution I last saw was either a workflow field update on the source record or a trigger. Try the field update path, if that doesn't work, you'll probably need a trigger. I don't think this issue has a purely formula-based solution, but as I said it's been a while since I've dealt with it.

Comment: I tried to avoid any dev work on this one but I don't think it's going to happen. Thanks anyway. It's really stupid and I raised an issue to salesforce but no response yet...

Comment: Yeah good luck with that, this issue has hung out there for years without resolution and I doubt it's very high on the priority list. If you can stand doing an IF statement in a formula that directly references RT ID's, I recall that you should be able to reference Account.RecordTypeId from Opp and it will resolve.

Comment: The thing is I need the name, the Id is easy to get :)

Comment: Yeah, so if you're averse to hardcoding a translation between Id and Name in your formula (either because they change, or there are too many of them, or you are working across non-ID-matching sandboxes), you'll need to go the way of workflow or trigger.